# How do I call a function/execute code automatically in Angular?

Tags: html, angular

I have code in a function that I need for initialization of other variables. However, this function doesn't get called unless i call it through another tag in html. Is there any way that i can initialize this function or write the code in a way in which the code gets executed automatically as soon as the project starts executing the the website loads?

Comment: So you need to execute it before angular starts, or just during angular bootstrapping? Maybe `ngOnInit` is what you are looking for? https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: Why don't you go through official documentation for learning angular https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at lifecycle hooks that are used in Angular, here is the link to the documents related.

[lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#oninit)

In here you can read about the OnInit() lifecycle hook which is triggered when a component is loaded ( after constructor ) and is an ideal place to look at initialising variables / calling functions.

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
   this.exampleText = 'Hello Component';
}
```

just make sure to implement it on your class like so

```
export class youClassHere implements OnInit {
 
    public exampleText: string;
    
    public ngOnInit(): void {
       //executing logic on component load
       this.exampleText = 'Hello Component';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement OnInit event and do it there. Take a look here [OnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit). Check here if you want to now more about [Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks). Alternative option is to use `constructor`. But that's executed on class initialization.

```
class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `OnInit` lifecycle in your class and call your function inside `OnInit` so that it gets called whenever your component gets mounted.